# find $u(x,\frac{1}{\pi^2})$ for $x\in (0,1)$, for $\partial u/ \partial t=\partial^2 u/ \partial x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,t)$ satisfy initial boundary value problem and $$\partial u/ \partial t=\partial^2 u/ \partial x^2$$ such that $x\in (0,1)$, $t>0$.

$u(x,0)=\sin(\pi x); x\in [0,1]$

$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$, $t>0$.

Then we have to find $u(x,\frac{1}{\pi^2})$ for $x\in (0,1)$.

I got my complementary function to be $\phi_1(x+t)+\phi_2(t-x)$.

How do I proceed after that?

Comment: Note that this is the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) in $1$D.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is NOT of the form $\phi_1(x-t)+\phi_2(x+t)$. That would be in the case of the wave equation: $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$.

You are given the Heat equation, $u_t=u_{xx}$, and in your particular initial value problem a solution is
$$
u(x,t)=\mathrm{e}^{-\pi^2 t}\sin(\pi x).
$$
This solution is obtained by standard separation of variables method.